# format python output to json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have written a Python script that outputs a long data structure (dictionary i called "celldict") in Json format. Here's a small part of it :

```
{
    "1224": {
        "OUT3FA_5": 12,
        "IN1": 37,
        "Total_IN1": 37
    },
    "1225": {
        "OUT3FA_5": 24,
        "IN1": 59,
        "Total_IN1": 22
    }
}
```

But what I would like to do is have something like this :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "Week":"1224",
            "OUT3FA_5": 65,
            "IN1": 85,
            "Total_IN1": 100
        },
        {
            "Week":"1225",
            "OUT3FA_5": 30,
            "IN1": 40,
            "Total_IN1": 120
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to format the json output with Python to get I what I want?
I do:

```
print json.dumps(celldict)
```

to get my output.
Any help would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put `celldict` *inside* another dict:

```
json.dumps({'success': True, 'data': celldict.values()})
```

You'll have to add the `Week` key to the `celldict` dictionaries first:

```
for d in celldict.itervalues():
    celldict['Week'] = '1238'
```

or use create a copy of each dict on-the-fly:

```
json.dumps({'success': True, 'data': [dict(d, Week='1238') for d in celldict.values()]})
```

The latter method, with some indentation, produces:

```
>>> print json.dumps({'success': True, 'data': [dict(d, Week='1238') for d in celldict.values()]}, indent=4)
{
    "data": [
        {
            "OUT3FA_5": 24, 
            "Week": "1238", 
            "Total_IN1": 22, 
            "IN1": 59
        }, 
        {
            "OUT3FA_5": 12, 
            "Week": "1238", 
            "Total_IN1": 37, 
            "IN1": 37
        }
    ], 
    "success": true
}
```

Reading between the lines, it seems as if the `1224` and `1225` keys in your input example are actually the week numbers you are referring to. If so, they are easily incorporated:

```
json.dumps({'success': True, 'data': [dict(d, Week=k) for k, d in celldict.iteritems()]})
```

would produce:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "OUT3FA_5": 24, 
            "Week": "1225", 
            "Total_IN1": 22, 
            "IN1": 59
        }, 
        {
            "OUT3FA_5": 12, 
            "Week": "1224", 
            "Total_IN1": 37, 
            "IN1": 37
        }
    ], 
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And what about the "Week" string that I would like to add too? You see what I need is to put `"Week"` before every key (represented by the numeric values 1224 and 1225) of my dict.

Comment: @user1734229: You can add those yourself by updating the dictionaries in `celldict` easily enough, right?

Comment: Yes this is great! But before I accept your answer, I see you've put 1238 in week while I want to get each week (suppose I have many weeks), how can I access dict's keys and assign them to `Week=` ?

Comment: @user1734229: What is the weeknumber *based* on? How do you determine it? I hardcoded the value because you didn't provide any information about how you determine that number. It's easy enough to set different numbers for each entry, if there is a rule to follow.

Comment: Well this structure actually comes from an Excel file, I iterate through it using the `xlrd` library, my first column contains all the weeks and my second column contains the other data. What I do is I calculate for each week value, the number of times "IN1" "OUT3FA_5" occurs (it's just summing basically). And that's what gives me the first structure. I do this : `celldict[first_column_cell][second_column_cell] += 1`

Comment: @user1734229: then include the weeknumber in your `celldict` structure in the first place. We cannot guess where that data comes from by ourselves. :-) At a glance, I guess `celldict[first_column_cell]['Week'] = weeknumber` would be what you are looking for.

Comment: @user1734229: Wait a sec, did you perhaps mean that the `first_column_cell` values are the week numbers? Thus the `1224` and `1225` numbers in your input example here? Then *make that clear* in your question. Your output uses *totally* different numbers, so there is no correlation for us to guess at there.

Comment: I am really sorry I didn't notice my mistake, I corrected my output. Thank you so much for helping me all the way.

Answer (score 0):

The json module follows the structure of your data, so to get your desired output you'll have to rearrange the data. You could construct a new dictionary like this:

```
data = []
for week, values in celldict.iteritems():
  v2 = copy.copy(values)
  v2['week'] = week
  data.push(v2)
newdict = { 'success' : true,
            'data' : data }
json.dumps(newdict)
```

(Disclaimer: I didn't test this code, but it should give you the basic idea at least)