# Generating Json file with custom variables Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to generate a json file preset with variables that are received from the user from input().The only method I found sorta-similar to mine is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607765/format-python-output-to-json), but it doesnt show how to generate a new json file.

An example of inputs:

```
Enter the name of the json file:
>>>file

Enter the width:
>>>2

Enter the height:
>>>2
```

Then these inputs are converted into a json file like so:

```
{
    "width": "2",
    "height": "2"
    "column": [
        {
            "0": "1255255255"
            "1": "1255255255"
        },
        {
            "0": "1255255255"
            "1": "1255255255"
        }
    ]
}
```

Every list of values correspond to a column, and the values within a list are a row. How would I generate enough columns and rows to match the width and height?

i.e.
a column:

```
        {
            "0": "1255255255"
            "1": "1255255255"
        }
```

a row:

```
            "0": "1255255255"
```

the "1255255255" value doesnt matter, it's just a placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to produce a python representation (lists + dicts etc.) of the structure you want and then use the json library to dump it to a file.

So in your case,

```
import json

# Get these from input
filename = "test.json"
width = 3
height = 5
placeholder = 1255255255

obj = {
    "width": width,
    "height": height,
    "column": [{row: placeholder for row in range(height)} for col in range(width)]
}

with open(filename, "w") as out_file:
    json.dump(obj, out_file)
```

Comment: Probably typo in your code - file shall be opened for writing `"w"`instead of reading `"r"`, otherwise `FileNotFoundError` or `io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable` is raised.

Answer (score 1):

I used list and dict comprehension to generate desired number of dictionaries with desired number of keys, then I used [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) to serialize dictionary to JSON formatted string (while providing `indent` parameter, otherwise generated JSON would be just one line) and saved that string to the file opened with [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) (the preferred way to open files).

```
import json
import os

filename = input("Enter the name of the json file: ")
width = int(input("Enter the width: "))
height = int(input("Enter the height: "))

# Append .json if user did not provide any extension
if not os.path.splitext(filename)[1]:
    filename += ".json"

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump({
        "width": width,
        "height": height,
        "column": [
            {
                str(row_idx): 0 for row_idx in range(height)
            }
            for column_idx in range(width)
        ]
    }, f, indent=4)

print("JSON saved to file {}".format(os.path.abspath(filename)))
```

Testing:

```
Enter the name of the json file: test_json
Enter the width: 2
Enter the height: 2
JSON saved to file C:\Users\Bojan\.PyCharm2017.3\config\scratches\test_json.json
```

Content of the `test_json.json` file:

```json
{
    "width": 2,
    "height": 2,
    "column": [
        {
            "0": 0,
            "1": 0
        },
        {
            "0": 0,
            "1": 0
        }
    ]
}
```